# Multiple Errors in .c include file while using union

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, include, header-files

I continuingly fail to find any error in the following (c)code. Yet the compiler is throwing errors on me.

This is the code in

FloatConverter.c

```
1  #ifndef FloatConverterh
2  #define FloatConverterh
3 
4  #include "FloatConverter.h"
5  #include <stdint.h>
6
7  #define MAXVALUE 6000
8  union Cast
9  {
10    double d;
11    long l;
12 };
13
14 int32_t float2int( double d )
15 {
16     static volatile Cast cast;
17
18    cast.d = d + 6755399441055744.0;
19    return cast.l;
20 }
21
22 // naive
23 int32_t f32ToInt16Digits( float f32 )
24 {
25     return ( ( int32_t )( f32 * 2 * MAXVALUE / 65535 ) ) );
26 };
27
28 // improved
29 int32_t f32ToInt16Digits2( float f32 )
30 {
31    return ( float2int( f32 * 2 * MAXVALUE / 65535 ) );
32 };
33
34 #endif
```

FloatConverter.h

```
extern int32_t f32ToInt16Digits( float f32 );
extern int32_t f32ToInt16Digits2( float f32 );
```

I'm sure the error lies within the include file. If I remove it (and all refrences) everything is back to normal and fine.

This are the errors that are put out by the compiler:

In FloatConverter.c

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'cast' 16
'cast' undeclared (first use in this function) 16
expected ';' before ')' token 25
expected statement before')' token 25
```

in FloatConverter.h:

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'f32ToInt16Digits' 1
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'f32ToInt16Digits2' 2
```

I'm grateful for any hints.

Comment: Why is there a semicolon after your function definitions? Also is that the whole content of *FloatConverter.h*? Don't you use include guards?  Why are there include guards in the implementation file?

Comment: The semicolon after the function definition was an experiment, they aren't hurting anyone I think. Yes it's the whole file. The Inclusion lock is misplaced, but this is not the source of the error (tested it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `union` to declare a variable of type `union Cast` like this

```
union Cast cast;
```

or create a type like the following

```
typedef Union Cast { ... } Cast;
```

after this you can use `Cast cast` or `union Cast cast` and both should compile correctly.

Also, include guards like

```
#ifndef __THIS_INCLUDE_FILE_H__
#define __THIS_INCLUDE_FILE_H__

// Contents of the file

#endif // __THIS_INCLUDE_FILE_H__
```

are meant to prevent including the same file multiple times, or rather it's content. They should not be inside a *.c* implementation file because implementation files can only be compiled once in a program or multiple definitions of functions and global variables will prevent compilation from succeeding.

Finally, be consistent with yourself. If you are going to use white space after an opening parenthesis and one before the corresponding closing parenthesis then do it so *ALWAYS*<sup>1</sup>. But don't do it in one place and then omit it in another.

Another thing, you need to include `stdint.h` before any occurrence of `int32_t` and that means, it should go before the function prototypes in your header file. In the posted code, you include it only after it and hence `int32_t` is undefined in the header file causing the another compilation error.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>You really shouldn't, it looks horrible.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! That eliminated the two errors in line 16. Well seems like there are multiple sources of error.

Comment: @a_random_Martin Please read the last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: I edited it and I will stick to it in the future :), furthermore there was a surplus bracket in the second defined function. Thanks for your time! Seems that I should have had a coffee this morning...

Comment: @a_random_Martin You didn't have coffee? I can't forgive you now! It's all your fault!